# How to handle exception in new operator in LINQ?

Tags: c#, linq, exception

I need to handle exception inside my LINQ, but I have no ideas how to do this. Here is my code:

```
    return (from element in m_Content.Descendants(Properties.Settings.Default.DataSourceTag)
            select new DataSource
            {
                Provider = Provider.Parse(element.Attribute(Properties.Settings.Default.SpProvider).Value),
                Template = element.Attribute(Properties.Settings.Default.TemplateAttribute).Value,
                Reference = element
            });
```

So, the problem in datasources attributes. How can I catch if one or more of them are null?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Instead of accessing `Value` property directly use an **explicit cast**.For example cast it to string or whatever the type of `Template` is.

```
Template =(string)element
         .Attribute(Properties.Settings.Default.TemplateAttribute),
```

It avoids the `NullReferenceException` if there is no `Attribute.`

Answer (score 0):

LINQ uses [*defered execution*](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/charlie/archive/2007/12/09/deferred-execution.aspx). Thus, the line you quoted in your question does *not* execute the constructor, and will *not* throw an exception.

The exception will be thrown when the LINQ query is executed. *At that point*, you need to add a try-catch block.

Example:

```
IEnumerable<DataSource> GetData()
{
    return (from element in m_Content.Descendants(Properties.Settings.Default.DataSourceTag)
        select new DataSource
        {
            Provider = Provider.Parse(element.Attribute(Properties.Settings.Default.SpProvider).Value),
            Template = element.Attribute(Properties.Settings.Default.TemplateAttribute).Value,
            Reference = element
        });   // no exception thrown here
}

void myMethod1()
{
    var data = GetData();    // no exception thrown here

    var lst = data.ToList(); // exception might be thrown here!
}

void myMethod2()
{
    var data = GetData();    // no exception thrown here

    foreach (var entry in data) // exception might be thrown here!
    {
        ...
    }
}
```

Comment: Or put exception handler in Provider.Parse().. And make own method for extraction element attribute where throw new exception if something is wrong.. right?